# Add a class to the body tag when a menu is enabled

Tags: menus

Question edited

How can I add a class to the body when the menu at the `menu setting > theme locations` is selected.

Like in this screenshot:

[image: theme locations]

And if I have two menus, can it add two different classes to the body tag?

I would like to use that class to control the nav toggle icon, etc.

Comment: Please edit to explain what exactly do you mean in "primary-menu is enabled".. Do you mean added, show, hovered on or something totaly different

Comment: I guess you used jQuery function to enable or disable the `primary-menu`.  So just use the same function add a class to the body.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [has_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu) to detect if the menu is configure in a [body_class filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters).

Something like

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse209469_body_class' );
function wpse209469_body_class( $classes ) {

    if (has_nav_menu('primary-menu'))
      $classes[] = 'primary-menu';

    return $classes;
}
```

If you have two menus you can change the condition to match both, or just do two filters. There is probably a way to enumerate all the menus and add classes for them but it is probably an overkill.